# What can I say about $P\bigl[Y-X \le\frac{1}{2}\bigr]$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent $U[0,1] $ variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random independent variables with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

What can I say about $P\bigl[Y-X \le\frac{1}{2}\bigr]$?

I tried doing the following:

$$P\Bigl[ Y \le X + \frac{1}{2}\Bigr]$$
Let $X + \frac{1}{2} = Z$. $Z$ is uniform on $\bigl[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\bigr]$

Then I evaluated $\int_{\!\frac{1}{2}}^1t\, dt$ but the result is wrong. 
Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, exactly.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am so sorry, it is indeed uniform.

Comment: Use the inverse transform method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Draw a picture of the unit square and shade the area that matters. Then you can find the answer without integrals (even without pencil and paper after you see the picture).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\int _0^{1/2} \int_0^{x+1/2} \, dy \, dx+\int _{1/2}^{1} \int_0^{1} \, dy \, dx=7/8$. You get this by using the fact that joint density is given by $f_{X,Y} (x,y) =1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq y\leq 1$ and $0$ for other values of $x$ and $y$. You just have to figure out the range for $x$ and $y$ from the inequality $y-x \leq 1/2$

Comment: _Can you give me some suggestions?_ Not _Please give me answer._

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_X(\cdot)$ be the density of $X$.

You have by the total probability theorem,

\begin{align}\Pr\left(Y-X\le\frac{1}{2}\right)&=\Pr\left(Y\le\frac{1}{2}+X\right)\\&=\int\Pr\left(Y\le\frac{1}{2}+x\mid X=x\right)f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=\int\Pr\left(Y\le\frac{1}{2}+x\right)f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^{\min(1/2+x,1)}1\,\mathrm{d}y\right)1\,\mathrm{d}x\end{align}

The rest is pretty straightforward.